# How to update last access date of files and folders in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I have observed that last "accessed date" of a file or folder on windows 7 does not get updated real time. It does not update even after refreshing the folder, renavigating to the folder and accessing its content and restarting the OS. How to update the "last accessed date" ?

Answer (score 4):

According to Microsoft's documentation of the Win32 [GetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320(v=vs.85).aspx) api:

> NTFS delays updates to the last access time for a file by up to one
>   hour after the last access. NTFS also permits last access time updates
>   to be disabled. Last access time is not updated on NTFS volumes by
>   default.

JanSchejbal is correct that the problem with last access times is performance, that it turns every read into an additional write.  Microsoft describes how the [`fsutil`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785435(v=ws.10).aspx) command can be used to modify the filesystem behavior.

Comment: Is there any way to manually update ?

Comment: Does this delay affect the displayed date? I would expect that the change is kept in memory (but not written to disk until 1 hour has passed), and when the date is requested, the in-memory value is shown.

Comment: so you are saying it can be manually updated, right ? do you know how it can be done?

Comment: @JohnWatson - Why do you want to know how it can manually be updated if your attempting to verify if the file has been modified?  Why are you worried about people changing you file without your knowlege there are easier ways to prevent that action.

Answer (score 3):

The last access date has been disabled for performance purposes, as it turns every read into a write operation [(source)](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/enable-last-access-time-stamp-to-files-folder-windows-7/). You can use `fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 0` to enable them, but this will hurt performance.

Comment: I dont think it is disabled. I can see last access dates for all folders, only thing is that data is not updated. I am not able to understand the frequency of update by the OS. So , how to make it real time or at least update it manually?

Comment: Disabling it means it is not updated. Existing dates are still preserved and displayed. What do you need it for? Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: To check if somebody has copied my data. So, if lastaccess is disabled, still system keeps the record of access date and time which can be retrieved by enabling the parameter ?

Comment: @JohnWatson: If lastaccess is disabled, the system does not keep any records of access to the data. Don't get your hopes too high - I would expect lots of virus scanners, search indexers etc. to bump that date for you, making it pretty useless unless you have a very controlled environment.

Comment: btw how to cross check using cmd what is the set value of `disablelastaccess` ?

Comment: `fsutil behavior query disablelastaccess`

Comment: the value is 1. Now, this is surprising, because I can see updated last access on some folders. Any idea what is going on ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7659/discussion-between-john-watson-and-jan-schejbal)

Answer (score -1):

"Is there any way to manually update?"
Yes. Several free software programs can change the Created date, Modified date, and Accessed date of any file to anything you want.

"What do you need [last access date] for?"
"To check whether someone has copied my data."

Windows has file auditing. (I've never used it.) When configured, it logs every access or attempted access to specified file(s).